# JQuery.Post() call to mvc controller from magento onepage checkout

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

Im doing a little messing around and on a learning curve with Magento, Jquery and programming and looking for some guidance with an issue Ive been stuck on.

I want to post some information to a controller of my custom module from one of the steps during onepage checkout.

The article at the following link has helped me understand how I could possibly achieve this and have followed that guide to the point that I am stuck at right now but my post call is posting back to my magento homepage as opposed to my specified controller action.

http://www.atwix.com/magento/ajax-requests-in-magento/

I suspect I need to do this a little differently as I am trying to post back from onepage checkout. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can make the jquery.post() call from onepage checkout to my magento controller action that is in my custom module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery isn't installed by default in Magento. [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) is. You want to do [this](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax) in your Javascript:

```
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/controller/action'); ?>');
```

Where `module` is the name of your Module and so on.

Comment: +1 for a solution to the answer, but I would still say for the original poster to use whatever he thinks is easiest long-term for him. It's no issue to run jQuery in noconflict mode.

Comment: True, but installing jQuery is a lot more complex than 'a little messing around'. The blog post that was linked to assumed jQuery was already installed, and based on the fact that installing jQuery is so complex, I assumed that that is not really what he was asking. I think a Prototype answer is more likely to be helpful than a jQuery answer.

Comment: +1 for promoting Prototype Vs jQuery. I have no preference between the 2, but if Magento comes with Prototype, why install another js library?