# Link PHP with Ajax Magento 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento2

I'm trying to create a simple "Register your interest" action. I have the front end working but I'm not sure how to link the AJAX to the PHP file. Where do I put the PHP file?

My current code for the AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "register-interest.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            type : "registerInterest",
                            email : userEmailLog,
                            user : userNameLog,
                            product : productTitle,
                            sku : productSku
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            JSON.stringify(response);
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            JSON.stringify(err);
                        },
                        complete : function() {
                            //$('.user-accept').addClass('unhide');
                            loading();
                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you check **url** variable is correct or not and then provide response any data like

```
success: function (response) {
                        JSON.stringify(response);
                    },
```

Comment: thats not quite what i was after. my problem is i don't know where to put the PHP file. Does it need to go in a module of its own?

Answer (score 1):

Your url value is:

```
"register-interest.php"
```

This implies that the php file that processes the AJAX request needs to be available at the same directory level as the page that includes the javascript file that is performing the AJAX request.

Example:

If your page is at `http://example.com/my/ajax/page.html`

Then the javascript will perform the AJAX request to the URL `http://example.com/my/ajax/register-interest.php`

Alternatively if you change the JS url value to read `"/register-interest.php"`, then the AJAX request will be made to: `http://example.com/register-interest.php`

Where you need to put it on your server depends on how your web server's webroot's folder structure is organised, but you should be able to work back from the URL the javascript will be requesting to work this out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm just having problem with where to put the php file in the Magento 2 file structure.

Comment: It depends. If the PHP file is a standalone php file that can handle a request directly, then place in Magento's public directory - in the source tree, this would be https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0/pub. However, I'd guess you probably want to have access to all of Magento framework's features when handling the AJAX response, in which case you should create an action on a controller, route it to a URL, and change the jQuery ajax call appropriately to reflect this.

Comment: Thats fab Benjamin! do you know of any guides for creating an action on a controller or something that will point me in the right direction?

Comment: or possibly an example?

Comment: The article linked to in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906892/jquery-post-call-to-mvc-controller-from-magento-onepage-checkout) may help.